# Working within agda's decideability framework

Tags: agda, theorem-proving, decidable

I'm having trouble using the string decideability.  First, I'm confused why it is so difficult to work with decideability in Agda, when in Coq it seems smooth as butter.  When I try to prove this simple theorem about strings, Agda unfolds this mess of a definition which is pretty much impossible to work with unless you know exactly what you are trying to do.  How can I work with string decideability via pattern matching that keeps the definition in tact?

Am using Stump's keep function instead of Agda's inspect.

```
keep : ∀{ℓ}{A : Set ℓ} → (x : A) → Σ A (λ y → x ≡ y)
keep x = ( x , refl )

--first roadblock
eqbStringrefl' : forall (b : String) →  true ≡ (b == b)
eqbStringrefl' b with keep (b ≟ b)
eqbStringrefl' b | (.true Relation.Nullary.because Relation.Nullary.ofʸ refl) , snd = {!!}
eqbStringrefl' b | (.false Relation.Nullary.because Relation.Nullary.ofⁿ ¬p) , snd = {!!}
```

Here is Agda's output:

```
-- Goal: true ≡
--       Relation.Nullary.Decidable.Core.isYes
--       (Relation.Nullary.Decidable.Core.map′
--        (λ x →
--           Agda.Builtin.String.Properties.primStringToListInjective b b
--           (Data.List.Relation.Binary.Pointwise.Pointwise-≡⇒≡
--            (Data.List.Relation.Binary.Pointwise.map
--             (λ {z} {z = z₁} →
--                Agda.Builtin.Char.Properties.primCharToNatInjective z z₁)
--             x)))
--        (λ x →
--           Data.List.Relation.Binary.Pointwise.map
--           (cong Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat)
--           (Data.List.Relation.Binary.Pointwise.≡⇒Pointwise-≡
--            (cong Data.String.toList x)))
--        (Data.List.Relation.Binary.Pointwise.decidable
--         (λ x y →
--            Relation.Nullary.Decidable.Core.map′
--            (Data.Nat.Properties.≡ᵇ⇒≡ (Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat x)
--             (Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat y))
--            (Data.Nat.Properties.≡⇒≡ᵇ (Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat x)
--             (Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat y))
--            (Data.Bool.Properties.T?
--             (Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat x Data.Nat.≡ᵇ
--              Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat y)))
--         (Data.String.toList b) (Data.String.toList b)))
-- ————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
-- snd : Relation.Nullary.Decidable.Core.map′
--       (λ x →
--          Agda.Builtin.String.Properties.primStringToListInjective b b
--          (Data.List.Relation.Binary.Pointwise.Pointwise-≡⇒≡
--           (Data.List.Relation.Binary.Pointwise.map
--            (λ {z} {z = z₁} →
--               Agda.Builtin.Char.Properties.primCharToNatInjective z z₁)
--            x)))
--       (λ x →
--          Data.List.Relation.Binary.Pointwise.map
--          (cong Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat)
--          (Data.List.Relation.Binary.Pointwise.≡⇒Pointwise-≡
--           (cong Data.String.toList x)))
--       (Data.List.Relation.Binary.Pointwise.decidable
--        (λ x y →
--           Relation.Nullary.Decidable.Core.map′
--           (Data.Nat.Properties.≡ᵇ⇒≡ (Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat x)
--            (Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat y))
--           (Data.Nat.Properties.≡⇒≡ᵇ (Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat x)
--            (Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat y))
--           (Data.Bool.Properties.T?
--            (Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat x Data.Nat.≡ᵇ
--             Agda.Builtin.Char.primCharToNat y)))
--        (Data.String.toList b) (Data.String.toList b))
--       ≡ Relation.Nullary.yes refl
-- b   : String
```

If I now apply a rewrite, the goal is simplified but we still have a mess in the hypothesis list.
When I try to ctrl-a, i get the following error, despite the goal being seemingly inferrable:

```
Goal: true ≡ true
Not implemented: The Agda synthesizer (Agsy) does not support
copatterns yet
```

Nonetheless, I was able to proceed as if the snd term was significantly cleaner, and then just applying the basic rules to arrive at final proof.

```
eqbStringrefl'' : forall (b : String) →  true ≡ (b == b)
eqbStringrefl'' b with keep (b ≟ b)
eqbStringrefl'' b | (.true Relation.Nullary.because Relation.Nullary.ofʸ refl) , snd rewrite snd = {!!}
eqbStringrefl'' b | (.false Relation.Nullary.because Relation.Nullary.ofⁿ ¬p) , snd = {!!}
-- eqbStringrefl'' b | (.true Relation.Nullary.because Relation.Nullary.ofʸ refl) , snd rewrite snd = refl
-- eqbStringrefl'' b | (.false Relation.Nullary.because Relation.Nullary.ofⁿ ¬p) , snd = ⊥-elim (¬p refl)
```

The last line is the completed proof.  Any suggestions would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By importing `Relation.Nullary` where the decidability notion is defined,you
will get access to the [`yes` and `no` patterns](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Relation.Nullary.html#1645) and Agda will happily resugar 
`(.true Relation.Nullary.because Relation.Nullary.ofʸ refl)` as `yes refl`
and the other one as `no ¬p`.

With respect to the goal's type, it comes from the fact that equality for strings is obtained by pointwise equality on lists of characters and equality on characters is obtained by the equality of their underlying representation as numbers. It's wordy but this gives us a definition recognised by Agda as safe & fairly efficient.

Comment: so is there any possible way of avoiding the expanded definition, or hiding it at least? also, do you have any idea why <ctrl-a> no longer works when I have an obvious reflexivity goal in the presence of this definition?

Comment: In the goal type? I don't think so. As for auto, it is unfortunately not maintained anymore and as soon as you start using copatterns (in this case relying on parts of the stdlib that are using copatterns) then it simply gives up because it has not been taught how to handle these things.